# Merging customer accounts based on email, name and billing address?

Tags: magento-1.7, customer

I am trying to modify an extension that automatically creates a customer account at checkout by emailing a password. However, the ext. checks if the customer email already exists in the database and if it does it merges the order into the exisiting account.

I would like to add additional criteria before we safely merge i.e name and billing address. If there is a match we can safely merge otherwise create a new account.

I've add the following to the indexController.php

```
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId($valueid)->loadByEmail($order->getCustomerEmail());
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId($valueid)->loadByFirstName($order->getCustomerFirstName());
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId($valueid)->loadByLastName($order->getCustomerLastName()); 
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId($valueid)->loadByBillingPostcode($order->getCustomerBillingPostcode());
```

And the complete controller file:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
class MyCustomExtension_MergeAccounts_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
    public function _CreateCustomerFromGuest($company="", $city, $telephone, $fax="", $email, $prefix="", $firstname, $middlename="", $lastname, $suffix="", $taxvat="", $street1, $street2="", $postcode, $region_id, $country_id, $customer_group_id, $storeId) {

                $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
                $street_r=array("0"=>$street1,"1"=>$street2);
                $group_id=$customer_group_id;
                $website_id=Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId)->getWebsiteId();;


                $default_billing="_item1";
                $index="_item1";

                $customerData=array(
                        "prefix"=>$prefix,
                        "firstname"=>$firstname,
                        "middlename"=>$middlename,
                        "lastname"=>$lastname,
                        "suffix"=>$suffix,
                        "email"=>$email,
                        "group_id"=>$group_id,
                        "taxvat"=>$taxvat,
                        "website_id"=>$website_id,
                        "default_billing"=>$default_billing
                );

                $customer->addData($customerData); ///make sure this is enclosed in arrays correctly

                $addressData=array(
                        "prefix"=>$prefix,
                        "firstname"=>$firstname,
                        "middlename"=>$middlename,
                        "lastname"=>$lastname,
                        "suffix"=>$suffix,
                        "company"=>$company,
                        "street"=>$street_r,
                        "city"=>$city,
                        "region"=>$region_id,
                        "country_id"=>$country_id,
                        "postcode"=>$postcode,
                        "telephone"=>$telephone,
                        "fax"=>$fax
                );


                $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
                $address->setData($addressData);

                /// We need set post_index for detect default addresses
                ///pretty sure index is a 0 or 1
                $address->setPostIndex($index);
                $customer->addAddress($address);
                $customer->setIsSubscribed(false);
                $customer->setPassword($customer->generatePassword(8));

                ///adminhtml_customer_prepare_save
                $customer->save();
                $disable_new_customer_email = (bool)Mage::getStoreConfig('guesttoreg/guesttoreg/disable_new_customer_email');
                if ($disable_new_customer_email != true) {
                    $customer->sendNewAccountEmail();
                }

                ///adminhtml_customer_save_after
                $customerId=$customer->getId();

                Mage::log("customerId:$customerId");

                return $customerId;
    } 
    public function postAction() {
        if($this->getRequest()->getPost()) {

            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            #print_r($data);
            #echo "ORDER ID: " . $data['customer_order_id'];

            $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
            $prefix = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/resources/db/table_prefix'); 
            $write = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
            $read = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

            $select_qry =$read->query("SELECT entity_id FROM `".$prefix."sales_flat_order` WHERE `increment_id`='".$data['customer_order_id']."'");
            $row = $select_qry->fetch();
            $entity_id = $row['entity_id'];

            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
            $order->load($entity_id); //needs entity_id NOT order_Id

            $store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
            $valueid = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($store_id)->getWebsiteId();
            //DUPLICATE CUSTOMERS are appearing after import this value above is likely not found.. so we have a little check here
            if($valueid < 1) { $valueid =1; }
            #exit;

            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId($valueid)->loadByEmail($order->getCustomerEmail());
            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId($valueid)->loadByFirstName($order->getCustomerFirstName());
            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId($valueid)->loadByLastName($order->getCustomerLastName()); 
            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId($valueid)->loadByBillingPostcode($order->getCustomerBillingPostcode());                        


            if ($customer->getId()) {
            $customerexistedmessage = true;
            $customerId = $customer->getId();
            /* SOME DIRECT SQL HERE. JUST MOVES THE ORDER OVER TO THE NEWLY CREATED CUSTOMER */
            $entityTypeId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity')->setType('order')->getTypeId();

            //1.3.x
            /*
            $select_qry = $read->query("SELECT attribute_id FROM `".$prefix."eav_attribute` WHERE attribute_code = 'customer_is_guest' AND entity_type_id = '". $entityTypeId ."'");
            $eav_attribute_row = $select_qry->fetch();
            $write_qry = $write->query("UPDATE `".$prefix."sales_order_int` SET value = '0' WHERE attribute_id = '". $eav_attribute_row['attribute_id'] ."' AND entity_id = '". $entity_id ."'");
            $write_qry = $write->query("UPDATE `".$prefix."sales_order` SET customer_id = '". $customerId ."' WHERE entity_id = '". $entity_id ."'");
            */

            //lets do a check first.. if we have existing guest orders prior to this point in time lets merge those too :)
            //1.3.x - 1.4.0.1
            #$select_qry = "SELECT ".$prefix."sales_flat_order.entity_id, ".$prefix."sales_order_varchar.value FROM `".$prefix."sales_flat_order` INNER JOIN ".$prefix."sales_order_varchar ON ".$prefix."sales_order_varchar.entity_id = ".$prefix."sales_flat_order.entity_id WHERE ".$prefix."sales_flat_order.customer_id IS NULL AND ".$prefix."sales_order_varchar.attribute_id = '".$attribute_id."'";

             $select_qry = "SELECT * FROM `".$prefix."sales_flat_order` WHERE customer_id IS NULL AND customer_email = '".$order->getCustomerEmail()."'";

             $rows = $read->fetchAll($select_qry);
             foreach($rows as $datafromexisting)
                { 
                         #print_r($datafromexisting);
                         $existingorder_entity_id = $datafromexisting['entity_id'];
                         #echo "CUSTY ID: " . $customerId . "<br/>";
                         #echo "ENTITY ID: " . $datafromexisting['entity_id'] . "<br/>";
            //1.4.x+
            $write_qry = $write->query("UPDATE `".$prefix."sales_flat_order` SET customer_id = '". $customerId ."', customer_is_guest = '0', customer_group_id = '1' WHERE entity_id = '". $existingorder_entity_id ."'");
            $write_qry = $write->query("UPDATE `".$prefix."sales_flat_order_grid` SET customer_id = '". $customerId ."' WHERE entity_id = '". $existingorder_entity_id ."'");
            //UPDATE FOR DOWNLOADABLE PRODUCTS
            $write_qry = $write->query("UPDATE `".$prefix."downloadable_link_purchased` SET customer_id = '". $customerId ."' WHERE order_id = '". $existingorder_entity_id ."'");

                }

            } else {
            $customerexistedmessage = false;

            $entityTypeId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity')->setType('order')->getTypeId();
            $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
            $prefix = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/resources/db/table_prefix'); 
            $write = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
            $read = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
        $select_qry5 = $read->query("SELECT subscriber_status FROM `".$prefix."newsletter_subscriber` WHERE subscriber_email = '". $order->getCustomerEmail() ."'");
        $newsletter_subscriber_status = $select_qry5->fetch();

            $customerId = $this->_CreateCustomerFromGuest($order->getBillingAddress()->getData('company'), $order->getBillingAddress()->getData('city'), $order->getBillingAddress()->getData('telephone'), $order->getBillingAddress()->getData('fax'), $order->getCustomerEmail(), $order->getBillingAddress()->getData('prefix'), $order->getBillingAddress()->getData('firstname'), $middlename="", $order->getBillingAddress()->getData('lastname'), $suffix="", $taxvat="", $order->getBillingAddress()->getStreet(1), $order->getBillingAddress()->getStreet(2), $order->getBillingAddress()->getData('postcode'), $order->getBillingAddress()->getData('region'), $order->getBillingAddress()->getData('country_id'), "1", $store_id);


            /* SOME DIRECT SQL HERE. JUST MOVES THE ORDER OVER TO THE NEWLY CREATED CUSTOMER */
            //1.3.x
            /*
            $select_qry = $read->query("SELECT attribute_id FROM `".$prefix."eav_attribute` WHERE attribute_code = 'customer_is_guest' AND entity_type_id = '". $entityTypeId ."'");
            $eav_attribute_row = $select_qry->fetch();
            $write_qry = $write->query("UPDATE `".$prefix."sales_order_int` SET value = '0' WHERE attribute_id = '". $eav_attribute_row['attribute_id'] ."' AND entity_id = '". $entity_id ."'");
            $write_qry = $write->query("UPDATE `".$prefix."sales_order` SET customer_id = '". $customerId ."' WHERE entity_id = '". $entity_id ."'");
            */
            //1.4.x
            $write_qry = $write->query("UPDATE `".$prefix."sales_flat_order` SET customer_id = '". $customerId ."', customer_is_guest = '0', customer_group_id = '1' WHERE entity_id = '". $entity_id ."'");
            $write_qry = $write->query("UPDATE `".$prefix."sales_flat_order_grid` SET customer_id = '". $customerId ."' WHERE entity_id = '". $entity_id ."'");

            //UPDATE FOR DOWNLOADABLE PRODUCTS
            $write_qry = $write->query("UPDATE `".$prefix."downloadable_link_purchased` SET customer_id = '". $customerId ."' WHERE order_id = '". $entity_id ."'");
            //UPDATE FOR NEWSLETTER
            if($newsletter_subscriber_status['subscriber_status'] !="" && $newsletter_subscriber_status['subscriber_status'] > 0) {
            $write_qry = $write->query("UPDATE `".$prefix."newsletter_subscriber` SET subscriber_status = '". $newsletter_subscriber_status['subscriber_status'] ."' WHERE subscriber_email = '". $order->getCustomerEmail() ."'");
            }

            }
            if($customerexistedmessage == true){    
                $message = $this->__('The email address already exists so the order has been merged to the existing account.');
            } else {
                $message = $this->__('Your account has been created and a email has been sent to you with their username and password.');
            }
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($message);

        }
        else {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__('Sorry this order could not be converted to a customer account.'));
        }
        #exit;

        if($this->getRequest()->getParam("backurl")!="")
            $this->_redirect($this->getRequest()->getParam("backurl"));
        else 
            $this->_redirect("/");
    }
}
```

However i get an error in var log

```
a:5:{i:0;s:84:"Invalid method Mage_Customer_Model_Customer::loadByFirstName(Array
(
    [0] => 
)
)";i:1;s:1190:"#0 /var/www/uk-dev3.thanedirect.com/htdocs/app/code/local/MyCustomExtension/MergeAccounts/controllers/IndexController.php(103): Varien_Object->__call('loadByFirstName', Array)
```

I know that the additional criteria I have added below:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId($valueid)->loadByEmail($order->getCustomerEmail());
```

Is causing the error but I don't what the correct parameters should be.

Could anyone provide me with some guidance please..?

Answer (score 1):

`loadByEmail()` looks for the customer entity with the e-mail address specified as a parameter. the methods you added do not exist. That's why you get that error.
What you are trying to do is not possible because Magento allows only one customer account per e-mail address. In other words, the e-mail address is unique.
That's why, the following scenario will fail. You have an account with the e-mail address `test@example.com` and with an address saved in the address book: '99th Some Road, London, UK'. A customer tries to checkout with the same e-mail address but sets the billing & shipping address to '77th Some Other Road, Liverpool, UK'. In this case, according to your specifications you will have to create a new account. That's not possible due to e-mail address already existing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, at the moment the module will merge the accounts if the email already exists but i would like to add a few more parameters before I merge the account. For example, if I checkout with test@example.com with address '77th Some Road, London' then a customer tries to checkout with the same email address but a different billing address the module will merge the account. That is the scenario I am trying to avoid by adding in a few more parameters to check before safely merging.

Comment: I understood that. But I just explained in the answer that you cannot add these constraints because the e-mail address has to be unique for the customer accounts. If you add these constraints, you will get an error if the the addresses don't match and you try to create a new account with an existing e-mail address.

Comment: I need to disable the merge account feature if the email account already exists I want to prevent the account being merged...